# Как добавить условие попадание даты в диапазон в Update запрос?

Tags: sql

Всем привет!
У меня есть таблица `location` . 
В ней 3 колонки `(adres, busy, dt)`

Мне нужно сделать такой запрос.

`UPDATE location SET busy = 1 WHERE adres = 'A01-01-01'`

К этому запросу нужно задать условие. Если `dt < @data` , тогда установить `busy = 1`, иначе ничего не предпринимать.

Comment: не лучше ли будет сделать проверку в php коде?

Comment: этот код будет использоваться в 1С

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE location SET busy = 1 WHERE adres = 'A01-01-01' AND dt < @data
```

Comment: Всё гениальное просто =)